# SAML reference documentation?

Tags: reference, saml, saml-2.0

i have been trying to implement SSO using SAML in Java.
for quite some time i have been referring to blogs by experts and some of the answers on your site.
I wanted to know if there is a standard reference document which defines all the protocol elements and attributes of SAML request/response and guidance for their use. I have been using it according to my own convenience without following any standards simply exchanging XML messages between web applications.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SAML specifications are available [here](http://saml.xml.org/saml-specifications)

Comment: This is a good starting point for navigating through the specifications: [link](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/21265/draft-hodges-HowToLearnSAML-01.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf is a good reference, but a good layman's explanation is https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=gUmMcecHN9s

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon as they will break when the link breaks. Post a summary of the links as well as the links.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Chris Dickson's answer , the following link also provides standard documentation for opansaml-java

> https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManual